# Docker compose packet forwarding between containers

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have 3 containers (C1, C2, C3) built using docker-compose. There are two networks in the compose file:

```
networks:
    testnet1:
        driver: bridge
    testnet2:
        driver: bridge
```

C1 is a member of testnet1, C2 is a member of both and C3 is a member of testnet2. So the topology looks like this:

C1 eth0 (172.19.0.2) --- eth0 (172.19.0.3) C2 eth1 (172.20.0.3) -- eth0 (172.20.0.2) C3

With net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1, I was thinking that if I add a route to C1 like this:

```
route add -net 172.20.0.0/16 dev eth0
```

And a similar route on C3 like this:

```
route add -net 172.19.0.0/16 dev eth0
```

that I would be able to ping 172.20.0.3 i.e. C2 would be used a hop and forward the packet along. However that doesn't work, I get destination host unreachable when attempting to ping. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This probbably has little or nothing to do with docker, i am not an expert, but i'm guessing your gateways are set wrong.

Comment: Ah yeah thanks. Got it working with: route add -net 172.20.0.0/16 gw 172.19.0.3 dev eth0 and route add -net 172.19.0.0/16 gw 172.20.0.2 dev eth0.